# Sporadic MathJax failure

Tags: support, mathjax

In the last couple of weeks, once in a while, MathJax has not rendered on my system (OS X).  In both Chrome and Firefox I see the markup rather than the rendered equations.  Is this a problem of my system, and if so is there a fix?  Or does the problem reside elsewhere, outside of my control?

**update**

Five hours after my OP, things are working again.  Must be an issue elsewhere.

Comment: Wow, that is *eerily* similar to what I've been experiencing! http://i.imgur.com/p70vvgU.png! I don't think it's to blame on our computers/browsers...

Comment: Happening here, too. Also, the MathJaX font seems slightly...thinner.

Comment: MathJax renders for me, but it's significantly slower than before. And the font has indeed changed. It looks a lot uglier (bad spacing, subscripts are too big, etc).

Comment: It still looks OK for me on Firefox / Ubuntu.  I noticed recently that the rendering changed.  The math initially renders quickly but in a 'thin' font and then, after a second or two, re-renders in a 'thick' font.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I'm pretty sure that's one of the major features in the new version (2.5): there's a quick-and-dirty rendering to let you get a sense of the math at first, and then later the full rendering kicks in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as obsolete.

Answer (score 9):

**Update 2015/03/30**: [CloudFlare reports](http://www.cloudflarestatus.com/incidents/f0nt7qzwln27) that the issues have been resolved.

Peter from the MathJax team here. Our CDN provider has been experiencing attacks on some of its DNS servers (see also this [thread on the MathJax User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/kR6qnNLoiIA/79IfdXOpVbIJ)).

This attack leads to erratic DNS resolution failures. We're sorry for the inconvenience this is causing users and we'll send out an update as soon as we get any news.

Comment: I updated the post -- the issues should be resolved now.